# Add additional 'description' field for defined roles / role metadata?

Tags: custom-field, user-roles, members

Is it possible to add an additional field for "description" to each defined role? (Administrator, Editor etc, plus custom roles).

I'm using Justin Tadlock's [Members Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) and have created some additional roles for which I have a page which displays users for each role. e.g. "Events Team", and I'd like to show a description for the role on this page.

I've tried searching for this but I can't find an answer. Various plugins like Custom Fields and Piklist don't seem to be able to do it either.

I'm fairly proficient with PHP so doesn't need to be a plugin based solution.

Thanks!

Adrian.

Comment: By default roles have not description but we can make a customize to add role description using wordpress option api, All roles have unique key. get_editable_roles() function provide all roles with name and key so i save a description in options table like update_option( 'editor_description', 'Editor Description' );

Comment: I'd suggest using a single option and a map, c.f. the existing `wp_user_roles` entry in `wp_options`, but this seems a reasonable way to do it.